# Json data not loading on easyui grid

Tags: jquery, json, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am trying to load json data to easyui datagrid but all the fields cannot dispay.Someone help  me resolve this problem

**Below is my datagrid code**

```
<table id="dg" title="My Users" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:700px;height:250px"
        url="./invoice/fetchInvoiceDetail.action"
        toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
        rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th field="invodQty"  width="50" >Quantity</th>
            <th field="items.unitDesc" width="50">Unit</th>
            <th field="items.invodPrice" width="50">Price</th>
            <th field="items.invodAmount" width="50">Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**And below is my Json  response:-**

{"total":18,"data":{},"errors":{"mainError":"Bad credentials"},"success":true,"targetUrl":"/","messages"
:{"mainMessage":"Sign In Successful"},"rows":{"items":[{"accName":null,"jbrnName":null,"lpodVat":"Y"
,"totalItemVat":1793.10,"unitDesc":"PEICE","invodDescription":"PACKING TAPE","invodId":7852.00,"invodInvId"
:1935.00,"invodQty":200.00,"invodUnitId":1.00,"invodPrice":65.00,"invodAmount":13000.00,"invodCreatedBy"
:8.00,"invodCreatedDate":"2014-08-15","invodUpdatedBy":null,"invodUpdatedDate":null,"invodLpodId":8589
.00,"invodPaidAmt":0.00}]}}

Comment: try to send empty string " " instead of null values in the json items.

Comment: make sure the field same name as your parsing field in json, in some cases it's case sensitive.